# Why is there a box floating on top of my other apps?

Tags: samsung, notifications, popup

I'm coming back to Android after many years, and trying to manage Notifications.  That's supposed to be accessible by holding a finger on a notification and a menu will pop up allowing you to adjust the app's notification rights.

Except something wild happens instead.  The menu flashes up for 1/4 second, and then, the undesired app opens in a "half-size window" that floats over my home screen, or anywhere else I try to go.  If I click away from it, it "minimizes" and becomes an icon at the top right corner of my home screen.  Tapping it there brings back the half-size window.

[image]

So clearly there's a *cool, productivity-enhancing feature* that I need to be red-pilled on.  Can anyone help?

- What is it?
- Is it inherent to Android, or a trick done by certain apps such as Mod Pizza?
- How do I get rid of an unwanted window/icon?
- How do I use it as intended?

Also, back on the notification screen, am I correct it's a timing thing on the finger-hold? Like "short" = go to the app, "medium" = adjustment menu, and "long" = do the above feature?  Can that be adjusted?

Answer (score 1):

> What is it?
> Is it inherent to Android, or a trick done by certain apps such as Mod Pizza?
> How do I use it as-intended?

**This is a Samsung feature called "pop-up view".**

Aside from the [split windows](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support), Samsung also offers [pop-up views](https://www.samsung.com/sg/support/mobile-devices/how-to-use-multi-windows-and-pop-up-views-on-galaxy-phone/) (similar to the [picture-in-picture mode](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture)) as an alternative for multi-tasking.

> How do I get rid of an unwanted window/icon?

To remove the pop-up window:

- Tap the small bar on the top of the window, then tap the "X" icon, or
- Tap and hold the small bar, then drag the window to the "X Remove" text on the bottom of the screen

To remove the minimized icon:

- Tap and hold the icon, then drag it to the "X Remove" text on the bottom of the screen

---

> back on the notification screen, am I correct it's a timing thing on the finger-hold? Like "short" = go to app, "medium" = adjustment menu, and "long" = do above feature?

Correct. The behavior is:

- Short tapping will open the app (or open the minimized notification)
- Medium holding will show the simple notification settings
- Long holding will allow the user to open the app in a pop-up view or full-screen view (similar to long holding the app from [the Recents screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents))

> Can that be adjusted?

As far as I know, no, it is not adjustable.